# Sintaxis invalida en Python con OpenCV

Tags: python

Buen día, quiero capturar un video en python con openCV por medio de este codigo, pero al momento de dar ejecutar me lanza este mensaje de error:

```py
if cv2.waitKey(1) &amp; 0xFF == ord('q'):
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Este es mi codigo completo:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
  # Captura video cuadro a cuadro 
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  # Las operaciones sobre los cuadros se hacen aqui
  gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  # Muestra el cuadro resultante
  cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
  if cv2.waitKey(1) &amp; 0xFF == ord('q'):
      break

# Cuando todo está listo, se libera la captura 
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema esta en el if, parece que estas usando un & como si escribieras un HTML (&) para hacer un AND.

```
if cv2.waitKey(1) &amp; 0xFF == ord('q'):
```

Lo solcionas de esta manera.

```
if cv2.waitKey(1) and 0xFF == ord('q'):
```

Espero te ayude.

Comment: Lo he modificado a como me has dicho, pero me sigue marcando el mismo error.

Comment: Era `and` en lugar de &&, ya modifiqué mi respuesta.

Comment: Si así era, ya se ejecuto el programa, muchas gracias!

Comment: Listo; Muy bien!